# Google reCAPTCHA v2 invalid domain for site key

Tags: validation, dns, recaptcha

I am currently trying to add reCAPTCHA on the client side and I have followed the documentation accordingly from both Google and reCAPTCHA's website.  However, for some reason I keep getting this error message:

[image]
I've placed my script tag in the head and my reCAPTCHA div just before the closing form tag.

```
<!-- Google reCAPTCHA API -->
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer>  </script>

<form action="URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" method="POST"> -->
    <!-- reCAPTCHA Widget Appears Here -->
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="darklight" data-sitekey="my_public_sitekey"></div> -->
</form>
```

Please let me know if you need to see more of my code.  From what I've read in other forums people had to disable domain name validation, however, that causes issues with verification.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After hours and days of research I've finally found a solution.  This error is actually a reCAPTCHA issue that still has not been fixed.  You can work around their protocol issues and disable domain check in advance settings.  However, that can potentially mess up the validation process.

Initially I was testing this locally `file:///users/file-path-to-my-file`.  Finally last night I found out you cannot use reCAPTCHA this way.  I ended up testing my site publicly and now it works just fine.  Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was also testing like that(`file://`). But after disable the origin/domain check, I can test on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace `my_public_sitekey` with your site key which provided by Google

finally, your cod should be like this

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="darklight" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>
```

if you are testing your site in localhost, you should get a reCaptcha key for `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually replaced my public site key with the one Google gave me.  I just removed it for the purpose of asking this question.  I suppose since it's not the private key I would've been okay but  either way that solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Oops!. It should work when you use _site key_  with _your site address_. Did you double check where_your site address_ of the _site key_ which using is correct?

Comment: By site address you mean the website domain correct?  If so, then the site key I used was for my site address.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion there.  So I only have one site address.  I see others that had this problem had more than one site address or were using a subdomain.  The format you gave in your answer is what I have done...still quite confused here

Comment: hey, i meant the site address is your website domain address. Did you generate the site key for recaptcha with http or https?

Comment: So I wasn't able to generate it for either one.  I kept getting an error, it would only generate a site key with "www" followed by the site address..

Answer (score 0):

Disable this option in settings:

Verify the Android package name of reCAPTCHA solutions.

This solved my problem.